# Why does the standard library implement conversions from each type to itself?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, identity, traits

On page 298 of [Programming Rust](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920040385.do) you can find the following statement

> The standard library automatically implements the trivial conversion from each type to itself: every type `T` implements `From<T>` and `Into<T>`

However it doesn't actually say why that would be useful or why the standard library would automatically do that? What's the reason for this?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: Isn't it more for genericity? So you can, for example, write a function that accepts `Into<T>`, and it will accept T?

Comment: That's also a very fair point

Comment: @SébastienRenauld please be mindful of how we use the word "safety". Rust has a pretty specific meaning for that word, and this is not an example of that.

Answer (score 14):

It can be convenient when writing functions/types with generic arguments. For instance, if I write a function:

```
fn do_something_with_string<S: Into<String>>(s: S) {}
```

That function will work equally for `String` and anything which can be turned into one.

Comment: When you say it like that, it makes a lot of sense. I'll select this as chosen in a few days if that's all there is to it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll months have been pasted... :)